# Present SKScene from UIVIewController after selection on UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a side scrolling menu for a project that includes multiple games. I want to let the user scroll a UICollectionView horizontally (inside my initial ViewController) and tap on it to load one of the games.

I've been trying to use:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if(indexPath.row == 1) {
    [self showSpinWheel];   
}

- (void)showSpinWheel {
    SKSceneLoader *spinLoaderView = [[SKSceneLoader alloc] init];
   [self presentViewController:spinLoaderView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

when a cell is selected, but it keeps crashing when I tap on it.

SKSceneLoader has this code but it doesn't matter, since it crashes even before loading it.

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

    if(!skView.scene) {

        skView.showsFPS = NO;
        skView.showsNodeCount = NO;

        // Create and configure the scene.
        SKScene * scene = [SpinWheel sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
         scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

         // Present the scene.
         [skView presentScene:scene];

        // background sound

    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
-[UIView scene]: unrecognized selected sent to instance
NSInvalidArgumentException, etc, etc.
```

How can I tell the correct view to load the scene? From what I understand I'm trying to load the SKCcene into UIView which is not correct. Do I need to load another UIViewController first and load the scene there? There must be a way to load a SKScene from a non-skcene scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the methods name suggests, `-presentViewController:animated:completion:` only accepts a `UIViewController`. The easiest thing to do would be to create a new `UIViewController` subclass that handles the creation of the `SKScene` and present that.

---

Based on your comments/edits the issue is with this line.

```
if(!skView.scene) { ...
```

The `view` property on a UIViewController is just a UIView by default. Since UIView doesn't have a `scene` property, thats the cause of the error. What you'll need to do is get it to be a SKView instead. Since you dont have a nib, the easiest way would be to override `-loadView` in SKSceneLoader to set `view` to a SKView.

```
- (void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
}
```

Comment: Sorry to sound like a noob (I am), I've never quite understood subclassing completely, but from what I understand I create a new file with UIVIewController as it's class. I then add the SKScene loading method (under viewWillLayoutSubviews) and use that to load the SKScenes? If I'm correct, I tried that but got the same error.

Comment: Could you post your code for creating and showing the scene? I would be easier to figure out a solution from that.

Comment: I updated the original question with the whole code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is SKSceneLoader a subclass of UIViewController? Does it have a nib?

Comment: Yes, UIViewController, no nib.

Comment: Yes! That solved! I moved if(!skVIew.scene) to -(void)loadView since it was only showing a gray scene and it's now loading the scene perfectly :D Thanks a million!